Display goes blue randomly, when connected to a TV
I have a system set up to provide a remote desktop display.  It is a quirky arrangement, so I'm going in to a lot of detail of how I got to this point.
I'm using some legacy hardware that we have a few spare of to -- Dell Wyse 3040.  Intel Atom x5 Z8350, 2GB RAM, 8GB eMMC flash.  The aim is to have them remote in to a Windows Remote Desktop Server.  Support for their own ThinOS is hard to find, and storage size limits what you can reload them with so I've installed Lubuntu with minimal apps option, and no swap.  I removed more apps: redshift, imagemagick-6-common, lximage-qt, okular and skanlite.  Updates applied. Unattended upgrade configured.  RAM usage consistently between 700MB and 800.  Xscreensaver and power management options disabled.
Latest BIOS (1.2.5 from Sept 2018) applied.
These devices are prone to hanging at the point they would power-off or reboot, and so a fix was found and applied: Three lines added to the bottom of /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
blacklist dw_dmac_core
install dw_dmac /bin/true
install dw_dmac_core /bin/true

followed by sudo update-initramfs -u.
They're also prone to flashing a black screen briefly, like the display driver is crashing.  The fix I've found is to apply GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT='quiet splash i915.modeset=1' to file /etc/default/grub and then run sudo update-grub.  I think this has reduced the frequency of the issue, not sure fully fixed it.  I'm theorising that if and when this bug occurs, some displays doesn't recover.  The display that it demonstrates the fault with is an LG TV (55LV340C).  The cable is a passive DisplayPort to HDMI.  Right now, everything is in test on my workbench.  Within half hour of the test start, it glitched and I rebooted, and it lasted nearly three hours before glitching again.
Three Wyse 3040 boxes configured this way.  Three LG TVs, I think they're identical too.  They're all glitching.
Non-admin user created and set to log in automatically.  Remmina is set to launch after log-in, connect to a Windows RDS where it will launch a PowerPoint slideshow.  x11vnc set so I can see the attached monitor's output and interact with the GUI.  When the display fault occurs, system still fully responsive by x11vnc. If I close all apps and log-out the user the display turns from blue to black, but does not say "No Signal".  Logging out of LXQt session disconnects x11vnc so I use SSH to reboot the device, everything works until next time.
EDIT for clarity: The Wyse 3040 boxes are running Lubuntu 24.04.  They are connected to the TVs by DisplayPort to HDMI.  This is where the fault appears to be.  They are running an RDP app into a Windows server, and are themselves being administered, through x11vnc and SSH, from a Windows laptop. These details included to give the reader an insight into the usage, but is probably irrelevant to the fault.
Any assistance provided would be hugely appreciated.

Update: one suggestion from elsewhere was to try i915.enable_prs=0 within /etc/default/grub but still it failed after about 2 hrs.  During this time, I have been running it with x11vnc disabled until it tilted.  Only then did I SSH in to start x11vnc.service and connect from my laptop, and everything within the remote screen suggests there is still an output to the TV.  I have now removed these GRUB kernel parameters related to i915

I thought I had found the fix, being this kernel parameter to add to GRUB.  When I applied it, the first reboot suggested permanently fixed, as it was stable for about 15 hours.  Since then, I've done a round of updates and rebooted, and it fell over within an hour or two.  Checking if this kernel parameter has persisted beyond this recent updates.
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT='quiet splash' change to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT='quiet splash i915.enable_dc=0'
Source https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=156009

Please don't use comments for additional information about the question. The comments are our channel to ask you for clarification. You should edit and update the question.
